# Failed to get driver instance for oracle and hikaricp

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

i m having exception when connecting to oracle db through springboot application.
but i can connect to this db using sql developer.

I used HikariCP for connecting db

part of the stacktrace is attach here

> Blockquote  018-06-25 13:09:21.778 ERROR --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication : Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'collectionApiController' defined in file [******]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'collectionServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'collectionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'collectionRepositoryImpl' defined in file [******]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [****/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [*****/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=****
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>       at lk.dialog.crm.collectionms.CollectionMsApplication.main(CollectionMsApplication.java:35)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) 
>   Blockquote
>
> Blockquote

public class AppConfig {

```
private String jdbcUrl;
private String user;
private String password;

@Bean
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Logger logger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}

public AppConfig(@Value("${application.datasource.url}") String jdbcUrl,
                 @Value("${application.datasource.user}") String user,
                 @Value("${application.datasource.password}") String password) {
    this.jdbcUrl = jdbcUrl;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;



}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    config.setUsername(user);
    config.setPassword(password);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(15);
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

}

> Blockquote

Comment: `: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl`, share your configuration

Comment: hi : i updated it

Comment: Can you show jdbcUrl value replaced with dummy values?

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@***.**.**.***:1521:******

Comment: hi @user7294900  does this information enough ??

Comment: Do you have ojdbc jar? which version?

Comment: it is  11.2.0.3  veriosn

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, Accessing using Spring Boot Framework we change the **driver** property to **driver-class-name** to make it work.